# secure way to limit access to a login form

Tags: php, security

I am trying to figure out a secure way to limit access to web based application. It will be used only by few user for internal company usage and I need a secure way to provide access to login form only for those few people. I tried doing this by creating file 'user.txt' and wanted to save it to each personal computer of those future users, so the login page first checks if file_exists and than shows the login form, otherwise it redirects the visitor.. Unfortunately I could not manage with Windows 7 computer permissions or path to file, but the script always says the file doesn't exists.. So now, I need to find another way to lock the login page.. Any ideas what more secure than IP address ? How I can else indentify those 5-6 user's computers?
Thanks !

Comment: A little bit random -- if you're afraid of the page showing up on Google, add `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,NOARCHIVE">` to the head.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way to identify a particular computer.

The purpose of having a login form in the first place is usually to limit access to select people, and that is usually sufficient.

If you want to go a step further you could use (for authentication) SSL client certificates which would have to be installed on the client computers.

Comment: Yes, I have access - do I need to by SSL crtificate or I can do the job with the free ones

Comment: @МариянМаринов You could use a self-signed certificate, install it on the client machines, and use this to sign the client certificates.

Answer (score 1):

`file_exists` only works on the server, it can't access files on the user's machine... imagine the security risks that would result in.

Instead, if it's for internal company usage then the obvious first step is to limit access to people on the IP address belonging to the company. You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get that information.

Next, it really doesn't matter how many people access the *login* form, since they need an account in order to log in. If you create the accounts yourself and require the user to change the password the first time they log in, then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, first file_exists works on Win XP - I've done it. Next IP is not a solution since people works from different places using same laptops, so computer indentification is more important than IPs..

Comment: So... what if I broke into a user's house and stole his computer? Should I get instant access to your site? It's much better to identify a user, which is what usernames and passwords are for in the first place.

Comment: :)) OK, than what else different than IP can you offer to indentify a computer?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [http auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to avoid writing extra code for handling login forms. create a user with some password and distribute them to your internal network users.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use htaccess and htpasswd? This is an easy way to make it safely.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP should use a login form to protect a login form?

Comment: So basically, the login page needs a login page?

Comment: @Crisp Beat you by two seconds :p

Comment: people often trying to enter where they are not suppose to.. So I am trying to fake them that nothing interesting on that login url.. I am trying ony to make visible the login form to the people supposed to login, the rest are hovered..

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to use it instead of the form, if he just needs to limit the access to them, and don't want to use a database!